# Migration from tomcat 7 to tomcat 10

Tags: java, migration

For migration, I updated javax imports to corresponding jakarta. It's failing with 500 internal server error while calling POST service

Code snippet from service class

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/m1")
    @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public String sayHello(AcceptRequest request, @HeaderParam("Accept") String contentType) {
        logger.info("Invoked API : /sayHello");
        return "Hello";

    }
```

Code snippet of DAO

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
@XmlRootElement(name="feature")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AcceptRequest {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AcceptRequest.class);
    
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String a;
    
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String b;
    
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String c;
}
```

During execution we are not even getting  "Invoked API : /sayHello" logger line.

Comment: An error 500 often has an entry in the server log